# trying to find shell command to remove common lines between 2 files from file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to find a shell command to remove common lines between 2 files (between the two commas), from a file.

So I know this command works to find the common lines between the files:

```
file1=/opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/PortParameter_E7_Single_cust_stats.csv
file2=/opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/PortParameter_E7_Bonded_cust_stats.csv

comm -12 <(cut -d ',' -f2 ${file1} | sort) <(cut -d ',' -f2 ${file2} | sort)
```

I'm trying to put that together with a `grep` command to remove the common lines.

For example, *PortParameter_E7_Single_cust_stats.csv*:

```
ABC: 1-1-1-21,12345678,13942
ABR: 1-1-1-22,23456789,3069
ABD: 1-1-1-33,34567890,796
ABE: 1-1-1-47,45678901,3187
```

*PortParameter_E7_Bonded_cust_stats.csv*:

```
ABC: 1-1-1-21,12345678,13942 //same
ABR: 1-1-1-22,23456789,3069  //same
ABD: 1-1-1-33,34567890,796  //same
ABE: 1-1-1-47,45678901,3187 //same
ACC: 1-1-1-21,12345679,13942
ACR: 1-1-1-22,23456780,3069
ACD: 1-1-1-33,34567899,796
ACE: 1-1-1-47,45678909,3187
```

So I would want to remove the first 4 in the *Bonded* file.

I know I can do this:

```
comm -12 <(cut -d ',' -f2 ${file1} | sort) \
         <(cut -d ',' -f2 ${file2} | sort) > deleteme2.out
```

so *deleteme2.out* should show:

```
12345678
23456789
34567890
45678901
```

Then I can do these:

```
grep -vwF -f deleteme2.out ${file2} > realAllBondedFixed.test
grep -vwF -f deleteme2.out ${file1} > realAllSingleFixed.test
```

Then it shows 0 length in this:

```
comm -12 <(cut -d ',' -f2 realAllBondedFixed.test | sort) \
         <(cut -d ',' -f2 realAllSingleFixed.test | sort) > commonShouldBeEmpty.test
```

So that works.  I want to put it all together in one command like this:

```
grep -vwF < comm -12 <(cut -d ',' -f2 ${file1} | sort) \
                     <(cut -d ',' -f2 ${file2} | sort) > realAllBondedFixed.test2
```

but get an error:

```
-bash: comm: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing a format problem, or what.  I tried parenthesis where the `<` after `-vwF` is but that didn't help.

I got the `grep` command from [grep to remove list of in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145079/remove-all-lines-in-file-a-which-contain-the-strings-in-file-b) and the `comm` part is from someone at my company.

If anyone has any help, I'd appreciate it.

**Clarification as requested:

final *PortParameter_E7_Single_cust_stats.csv*:

```
(it would be empty, if every line has the common part between the commas)
```

final *PortParameter_E7_Bonded_cust_stats.csv*:

```
ACC: 1-1-1-21,12345679,13942
ACR: 1-1-1-22,23456780,3069
ACD: 1-1-1-33,34567899,796
ACE: 1-1-1-47,45678909,3187
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit about your desired output? You have great input examples, but you've talked around what the output is that you want.

Comment: Write a shell script instead of a single super-long shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try piping `comm` to `grep`:

```
file1=/opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/PortParameter_E7_Single_cust_stats.csv
file2=/opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/junk/PortParameter_E7_Bonded_cust_stats.csv

comm -12 <(cut -d ',' -f2 ${file1} | sort)  <(cut -d ',' -f2 ${file2} | sort)  |
grep -vwF > realAllBondedFixed.test2
```

Note:  the error in the *OP* code was using `<` to send command output to `grep`.  `grep` needs input from a file, or *stdin*.  When the shell sees:

```
grep -vwF < comm ...
```

It doesn't run the `comm` util, rather it looks for a *data file* named *comm* to send to `grep` -- but there's no such file, so it it gives the error `bash: comm: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 1):

Does it only have to be using grep? Here's another kind of solution if grep is not necessary.

```
cat PortParameter_E7_Single_cust_stats.csv PortParameter_E7_Bonded_cust_stats.csv | 
sort | uniq -d | cut -d ',' -f2 > output.txt
```

Output.txt:

```
12345678
34567890
45678901
23456789
```

Comment: That's just a new way to get the common part.  I need to remove the lines with the common part from both files. Thanks for trying!

Comment: I'm going to request that people do not down vote this person because I appreciate the effort in trying.